# Avoiding arithmetic overflow

Tags: java, c, math, precision

Assume you have 2 positive `long` values `a` and `b` which are greater than `2^32` (and smaller than `2^63`), and an long integer `c`. 
What is the best way, in java and\or c, to perform operations such as

```
(a*b)%c
```

while avoiding arithmetic overflow.

Edit : 
c is around `2^34`, and sometimes both a and b are just between `2^32` and `c`...

I finally avoided using `BigInteger` for the specific situation I was in. Indeed, It was possible to know one divisor of both `a` and `b` (not always the case), so I would use the arithmetic properties of `modulo` to my advantage.

Comment: assuming `long` is a 64-bit type ...

Comment: `gcc 4.6` provides the type `__int128` as an extension: [*Support for a new data type __int128 for targets having wide enough machine-mode support.*](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html).

Comment: if c is exactly 2^34 or any power of 2, the result will be the same whether you have an overflow or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming everything's positive, then you can use the following mathematical identity:

```
(a*b)%c == ((a%c) * (b%c)) % c
```

Of course, this still doesn't eliminate the possibility of overflow.

The easiest way to completely avoid the issue is to use a big-integer library.

Comment: yes this is what I have. c is around 2^34, and sometimes both a and b are just between 2^32 and c...

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the right side is safe from overflow if `c <= sqrt(LONG_MAX)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can go even further than what @Oli Charlesworth suggests in his (good) answer. You can decompose in factors `a` and `b` (not necessary in all the prime factors, a partial decomposition might be enough) and perform the modulus in any intermediate result of the multiplication. Although this is likely to be more costly than going for the bignum, as it will involve quite a few divisions and they are expensive.

Comment: Thanks. Actually that's what I did. Usually this decomposition is costly, but I realized that In my case It was not (due to how the numbers were generated in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

In Java I would use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#remainder%28java.math.BigInteger%29):

```
BigInteger bd = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(33);
System.out.println(bd.multiply(bd).remainder(BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(34).add(BigInteger.valueOf(1))));
```

Comment: ...`BigDecimal`, and not `BigInteger`?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to solve your problem without higher precision arithmetics, and at least LLVM's optimizer agrees.

If 128-bit math is not available natively, you'll need to use a general-purpose big integer library, or take the bits you need from a less general implementation like [Math128](http://svn.gnucash.org/docs/HEAD/group__Math128.html) from GnuCash.